# Items in list are not getting same permissions as list itself

Tags: list, permissions, item

I'm new to this list.

I have a SharePoint 2010 list (task) that inherits permissions from it's parent.  When a task item is created, the email is sent to the assignee but there are no (none) permissions on that item and I see the "inherit from parent" on the item which means to me that the item didn't take the same permissions as the list has.  I've created 2 other task lists and they do the same thing.  Where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you see "inherit from parent" on the item, what makes you think it is *not* inheriting permissions from its parent (the list, which in turn is inheriting from *its* parent, the site)?

Comment: I though that if I looked at the premissions of the list (which is inherited from parent), then the Items in the list would receive the same permissions.  Since I seen the Inherit from Parent at the Item level permissions, that meant that it is not inheriting from parent (which is what the list level permissions are).

Comment: Ah, so you mean you see the "Inherit from parent" button in the ribbon which will allow you to re-attach the permission inheritance?  If yes, then you are correct, that would indicate that permission inheritance is broken.  Not sure what to tell you in that case, I do not have much experience with task lists, so I don't know why that behavior might be happening.

Comment: How is a new task generated?

Comment: I originally discovered a problem because a workflow would create a task but nobody had permissions.  Then I created tasks directly within the Tasks list but still the same results.

Comment: Conclusion: I created 2 other task lists in the same site, and task item permissions did not work for either of those task lists.  Also, I used the Tasks template when creating.  I moved my library to a different SP site that already had a task list and the workflow and tasks worked perfectly.  Thank you for your comments.